# facebook live search using php jquery mysql, showing 5 results how to show the rest?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, search, live

hello i'v built a search, using MySQL, PHP and jQuery,
this is the search query using Prepared Statement..

```
$sql = "SELECT singer_name FROM singers WHERE singer_name LIKE ? LIMIT 5";
```

now what i want to do is show only 5 results but i want to also show a button with the REST of the results
like when you search in facebook the show only 8 of the friends and then a button with "see more resutls for ? showing top 8 results",

how do they do that ? , i'm sure it's fairly simple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT has 2 parameters with which you can fetch range of results instead of just first 5.

Check out an article on [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Example,

`$sql = "SELECT singer_name FROM singers WHERE singer_name LIKE ? LIMIT 5, 5";`

The above SQL will retrieve results from 5 to 10.

Update:

If you want to show results like "showing first 5 out of 20" then you need to first count the total number of results then apply LIMITs.

`$sql = "SELECT COUNT(singer_name) FROM singers WHERE singer_name LIKE ?";`

Comment: i need to retrive results from 1 to 5 and the rest of the results i want to show if there is more results just like facebook search...

Comment: You then need to first COUNT() all results available then you can show "showing 1 to 5 of 100 results".

Comment: so, do i need to query the database twice?

Comment: yes, for knowing the actual count. But if you want to avoid querying twice then you can fetch one extra record, like LIMIT 6 then check if 6 results were found, if yes then you can say "show more results". Otherwise, if less than 6 results were found you know that no more results were found.